# Bootstrap dropdown with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an application which allows user to select 3 values example: Hi, Hello an Hey.

By default the user gets a message saying he "select a value". Problem is i dont understand how to update the value of ng-model when a user selects either of the 3 values. I need the new selected drop down value in ng-model and when i save i have a function that updates the value in my database.

Here's the code

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-model="audit.data">{{audit.data}}
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a function that updates the value in the controller, then attach in each element

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li data-ng-click="updateValue('Hi')"><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
    <li data-ng-click="updateValue('Hello')"><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
    <li data-ng-click="updateValue('Hey')"><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
</ul>
```